# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'confidence'

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, chatbot, chatterbot, telegram-bot

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot e gostaria que ele só respondesse se tivesse determinado nível de confiança na resposta.

```
# -*- codding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import telebot
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TEM UM CÓDIGO DO TELEGRAM AQUI")

#Futaba original
def bot_convencional(message):
    chatbot = ChatBot("Futaba")
    trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
    for arquivos in os.listdir('arquivos'):
        chats = open('arquivos/' + arquivos, 'r').readlines()
        trainer.train(chats)

    resposta = chatbot.get_response(message) #ESSE GET DENTRO DO IF DA ÚLTIMA FUNÇÃO
    resposta = str(resposta) 

    mensagem = open("arquivos/teste", "w")
    mensagem.write(resposta)
    mensagem.close()

#Recebe e envia uma resposta inicial
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["help", "start"])
def enviar_mensagem(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hey")

#Recebe qualquer outra mensagem
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def mensagem(message):
    bot_convencional(message.text)
    resposta = open("arquivos/teste", "r")
    resposta = resposta.read()

    if float(resposta.confidence) > 0.5:
        bot.reply_to(message, resposta)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Como você está se sentindo?")
bot.polling()
```

O problema é que quando eu tento usar o confidence dá o erro

> if float(resposta.confidence) > 0.5:
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'confidence'

Já usei confidence em outro chatbot e não entendo porque está dando esse problema dessa vez. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu queria colocar o get.response da função bot_convencional dentro do if do mensagem.

Comment: Porque `resposta` será o conteúdo do arquivo `arquivo/teste` e isso sempre será uma string. No Python a string não possui o campo `confidence` como está tentando acessar. Se o conteúdo do arquivo for um JSON ou qualquer outro formato estruturado você precisa primeiro avaliá-lo antes de utilizá-lo, com a biblioteca `json`, por exemplo.

Comment: Ah, meu confidence tá tentando pegar a última declaração do usuário e não o corpus dentro da pasta arquivos. Vou colocar o código todo na pergunta: Tem como me dizer como eu colocaria o get.response no if do confidence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para o `confidence` eu precisava a acessar o `chatbot.get_response(message)`. Para isso, criei uma variável chamada corpus pra armazenar esse `corpus = chatbot.get_response(message)`, tornei ela global e acessei pelo `if` do `confidence`.

FUNÇÃO QUE ARMAZENA O CHATBOT

```
def bot_convencional(message):
    chatbot = ChatBot("Futaba")
    trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
    for arquivos in os.listdir('arquivos'):
        chats = open('arquivos/' + arquivos, 'r').readlines()
        trainer.train(chats)

    resposta = chatbot.get_response(message)
    resposta = str(resposta)
    global corpus
    corpus = chatbot.get_response(message)

    mensagem = open("arquivos/teste", "w")
    mensagem.write(resposta)
    mensagem.close()
```

FUNÇÃO QUE RESPONDE AS MENSAGENS

```
#Recebe qualquer outra mensagem
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def mensagem(message):
    bot_convencional(message.text)
    resposta = open("arquivos/teste", "r")
    resposta = resposta.read()

    if float(corpus.confidence) > 0.5:
        bot.reply_to(message, resposta)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Como você está se sentindo?")
bot.polling()
```

Eu não sei se isso é certo, mas funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

O problema consiste em você armazenar um objeto Python em forma de *string* no arquivo, posteriormente lê-lo também como *string* e utilizá-lo como se fosse o mesmo objeto inicial. NO momento que você grava o objeto como *string* no arquivo você deixa de tê-lo como um objeto do tipo original; o mesmo passará a ser um objeto instância de *string*, com os campos de *string*. Não existe o campo `confidence` na *string*, talvez apenas no tipo inicial do seu objeto.

Você grava um objeto como *string* no arquivo:

```
#Futaba original
def bot_convencional(message):
    ...
    resposta = chatbot.get_response(message) #ESSE GET DENTRO DO IF DA ÚLTIMA FUNÇÃO
    resposta = str(resposta) 

    mensagem = open("arquivos/teste", "w")
    mensagem.write(resposta)
    mensagem.close()
```

Você lê o arquivo e acessa o campo `confidence` de uma *string*, gerando o erro citado na pergunta:

```
#Recebe qualquer outra mensagem
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def mensagem(message):
    ...
    resposta = open("arquivos/teste", "r")
    resposta = resposta.read()

    if float(resposta.confidence) > 0.5:
        bot.reply_to(message, resposta)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Como você está se sentindo?")
```

Se você precisa persistir um objeto em arquivo para utilizá-lo posteriormente, você precisará utilizar alguma técnica de serialização. No Python existe a biblioteca nativa [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) que faz isso.

Grava um objeto serializado em arquivo:

```
obj = {'foo': 'bar'}

with open('arquivo.pickle', 'wb') as stream:
    pickle.dump(obj, stream)
```

Lê um objeto serializado a partir do arquivo:

```
with open('arquivo.pickle', 'rb') as stream:
    obj = pickle.load(stream)

print(obj['foo'])  # 'bar'
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-390135)</sup>